# Have a listen vs have listens vs have listen

Tags: grammaticality, difference, light-verbs

1. Have a listen to the CD.
2. Have listens to the CD.
3. Have listen to the CD.

Are they correct?
Can countable nouns take plural forms with this kind of delexical verbs?

Comment: Only #1 is idiomatically and syntactically valid, but note that it's an extremely colloquial usage. The *standard* version here is simply ***Listen to the CD*** (which is an "imperative" construction, with implied subject ***you***, the addressee).

Answer (score 1):

This kind of usage is common for sensory verbs. If you look at this [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/listen) entry for Listen, you will find this definition for the noun form:

> **listen**
>    noun
>      [in singular] An act of listening to something:
>      *radio plays are definitely worth a listen*

The [in singular] bit means that the noun is only valid as a singular noun- not plural. Looking at your three sentences:

> Have a listen to the CD.

This is valid, because **a listen** is singular, and listen can be a singular noun.

> Have listens to the CD.

This is not valid, because **listens** is a plural noun, and listen cannot be a plural noun, only singular.

> Have listen to the CD.

This is not valid, because there is no determiner (**a** or **the**). You can only omit the determiner for non-count nouns like **peace** and **sugar**, and listen cannot be a non-count noun, only singular.

The following words are documented as working in the same way: [watch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/watch), [read](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/read), [think](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/watch) and [sniff](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sniff). Other sensory words seem to work the same way, for example [smell](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smell), [taste](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/taste), [feel](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feel) and [shufti](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shufti), but they are not marked as singular-only for this usage.

Comment: When the OP says *delexical verb*, they're almost surely referring to the light verb *have*.

Comment: @snailplane, thanks for pointing that out. I have remove that comment from my answer.